# Vertical and horizontal scrolling on one page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want this effect:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aSKYijT.png] 
(blue is the visible part for user)

structure of the page looks like this:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<div id="page2"></div>
<div id="page3">
 <div id="page3-1"></div>
 <div id="page3-2"></div>
 <div id="page3-3"></div>
</div>
<div id="page4"></div>
```

I want to make leftmenu points to take me with a smooth scroll on click to a certain point of the website. I found this nice function for this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It works great, but when I add one more a little modified (to target different anchors `$('#page3 a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {`) and with `scrollLeft: target.offset().left` (for that horizontal scroll page) , it works only if there are overflows.

I made `overflow: hidden` for every page and `overflow-x: scroll` to that certain page that should scroll horizontally (to remove white space on the website) and then it doesn't work. maybe i should target different anchors. It is in Joomla. I think I am very close but can't figure it out. thanks!

Comment: Someone else already figured it out for you. You want to have a look at plugins like Fullpage :  http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage

Comment: hm, looks nice. don't you think i would have to change a lot of stuff instead of changing some of my code i have right now?

Comment: Like all plugins, you'll have to use its markup. But in the end, it will save you a lot of time and avoid a lot of trouble.

Comment: hate to modify markups in Joomla templates and modules. I really even dont know how, cause everything there is hidden. Any solution doing it thw way i asked please?:)

Comment: Ah, I don't know Joomla at all. I don't use this kind of stuff (I hate Wordpress) precisely for the reason you said : lots of stuff is hidden and customizing anything is a nightmare. So I always go full custom, from scratch.